# How to check the user owns our game in steam by web API?

Tags: steam

There is a method `GetOwnedGames` (https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Steam_Web_API#GetOwnedGames_.28v0001.29)
but it does not work if the user has set up a private profile.

Are there any other ways or methods to find out that the user owns our game?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The colleague has found more complete documentation of the api steam methods.
There is a method for obtaining information about whether the user owns our game.
https://lab.xpaw.me/steam_api_documentation.html#ISteamUser_GetPublisherAppOwnership_v1

Answer (score 0):

**No, there is no other way than the API you linked.**

By accessing a user's owned games you are investigating the user's private space. So Valve made sure that the user must give explicit permission by settiing their account to public. If it is private Valve makes sure noone can see the user's private acivities for legal reasons.

Alternatively you could browse public lists of user accounts but you cannot ask for a specific user that are not on the list: https://steamdb.info/stats/toplevels/, https://steamid.eu/top-hours-played/